# Using Spring and Jackson to Render JSON without affecting all Views

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring-mvc

[Spring MVC AJAX and JSON using Custom View Resolver, and Custom View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121252/spring-mvc-ajax-and-json-using-custom-view-resolver-and-custom-view)

Here I've gotten a view to display JSON by adding ".json" to the end of a URL, but using this method a visitor to the site can just put .json at the end of any URL they please and often it will result in an exception that gives too much information regarding the back end code.

I could catch the exception and provide a more user friendly error message, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to handle this since the times that I'd want to convert an object to JSON is actually quite limited and will really only be used for administration pages, is there a way to limit this feature to specific URLs, controllers, or controller methods?

Edit: This isn't about URLs that aren't mapped giving exceptions, It's about real URL's with ".json" after it that are mapped trying to render their contents as JSON when that isn't what is needed

I'm not worried about the exception I'm getting, it makes sense that I'm getting it, I'm saying that some URL's, in fact MOST URLs shouldn't be able to be taken as JSON, and putting ".json" after it should just return a 404

Comment: Post your web.xml and servlet.xml configuration. When configured correctly it should return a 404 when a URI isn't mapped to a controller, but obviously this isn't the case. Post the Exception and also post your annotated controller + methods.

Comment: this isn't a bug, so the exception I get is not important, but if you're interested the exception is thrown because it's trying to parse things as JSON that don't make sense to do so.  I clarified my question a bit, but this is not about avoiding an error, it's setting up the site to only return JSON when I want it to, and the controller explicitly allows it, otherwise JSON should not be produced

Answer (score 1):

I think is a problem more about security. If you're using a framework like Spring Security you can control that some URL like **.json can only be reached by some users (for instance the administrator, if they're only used in the admin pages).

Comment: While I agree that this is a reasonable approach, I'm interested in other answers.  I am fully willing to abandon the ".json" URL's entirely, and would prefer to have a simple way to specify controller methods that return JSON, than add a security aspect that is necessary because of a small subset of controller methods

Comment: In Grails you can say "return myThing AS JSON", I like that style approach more for this kind of use case

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this: [Configure Spring's MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747261/configure-springs-mappingjacksonhttpmessageconverter)

Basically, you can do everything without views or viewresolvers by using [@ResponseBody](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody) and [MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-mapping-json-converter)

Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/data")
@ResponseBody
public TestFormData dostuff() {
    TestFormData data = new TestFormData();
    data.setName("myname");
    return data;
}
```