# Configure Spring's MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am using `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` in Spring MVC to automatically serialize objects like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/*/getAccount", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Account getAccountAction() {
    Account account = accountService.getAccount();
    return account;
}
```

Is it possible to configure which properties of the object are serialized? In my example, `Account` has 3 collections as properties and serializing all these contents would result in a huge object tree. Here I only want to return the flat object.

Sincerely,
Erik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you already try to use the Jackson Annotations?

There is the Annotation [@JsonIgnoreProperties](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.5.3/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) that can be used to ignore a given list of properties for serialization on class level and there is [@JsonIgnore](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.5.3/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) to mark properties to ignore for serialization on field level.

Answer (score 0):

I could figure it out: Configure Jackson with annotatons, it is described in detail in the Jackson configuration.